# Recurring payments: how to specify an initial payment TAX value different than the subsequent cycles?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

If I do a request with the INITAMT equal to the recurring payment amount, it works.

But if I try to bill a different INITAMT (and so different TAX), I get this error:

```
Tax calculation mismatch. The tax amount for the regular non-trial billing period is different than the sum of the tax for each item in the cart.
```

---

**My actual request:**

I have an initial payment of 4.84€ **including 0.84€ of VAT tax**.

The next month the amount to bill should be 25.09€ (including 6.09€ VAT).

The request I send is basically this:

```
Method: CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile
"CURRENCYCODE":"EUR",
"INITAMT":4.84,
"TAXAMT":0.84,
"DESC":"Subscription",
"BILLINGPERIOD":"Month",
"BILLINGFREQUENCY":1,
"AMT":29,
"L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0":"Digital",
"L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0":"Subscription",
"L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0":29,
"L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT0":6.09,
"L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0":1
"PROFILEREFERENCE":"51a1f8f4732baf580a000031",
"PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INVNUM":"51a1f8f4732baf580a000031",
"INVNUM":"51a1f8f4732baf580a000031",
"PROFILESTARTDATE":"2013-06-26T11:59:12+0000",
```

And the response:

```
"TIMESTAMP":"2013-05-27T10:55:46Z",
"CORRELATIONID":"969d07e2cef8a",
"ACK":"Failure",
"VERSION":"74",
"BUILD":"5908853",
"L_ERRORCODE0":"10004",
"L_SHORTMESSAGE0":"Tax calculation mismatch.",
"L_LONGMESSAGE0":"Tax calculation mismatch. The tax amount for the regular non-trial billing period is different than the sum of the tax for each item in the cart.",
"L_SEVERITYCODE0":"Error"
```

---

I'd like to do this with the **INITAMT** value, so that the user can see the two purchases as correlated in the Paypal private area (ie: a subscription with an inital payment).

Otherwise I'll have to do a separate DoExpressCheckout for the initial payment.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that you cannot (I believe) set a tax amount for the Initial Amount.

The TAXAMT is for the recurring payment, not the Initial Amount.

Your statement is saying "Billing 29€ with a tax of 0.84€".

However your item list says the tax should be 6.09€

Change your TAXAMT to 6.09€ and it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to confirm what I suspected... sure it's strange that Paypal didn't think of it. However, I've just fixed it by removing the TAXAMT and L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT0, it's better to have the initial payment and the subscriptions correlated in the paypal account, than the tax information.